# Диспетчер удаленных приложений RemoteApp (Powershell )

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2008-r2

Собственно вопрос, есть сервер 2008R2 на нем RDS и через какой-то промежуток времени у пользователей исчезают значки с удаленного рабочего стола. Лечится очень просто - тыканьем по кнопке обновить в "диспетчере удаленных приложений RemoteApp", собственно вопрос, а есть команда в Powershell, чтобы обновлять список этих значков (приложений)? Честно, гуглил, не нашел ответ*(

Comment: Плохо гуглили: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/8c5681f8-0ceb-40a7-8d0a-8edfde050703/powershell-to-update-remoteapp-and-desktop-connections?forum=winserverTS

Comment: там не про то речь, нужен именно Диспетчер удаленных приложений RemoteApp, он же, RemoteApp Manager в англ версии

Comment: Могу только предложить взять в руки Process Monitor и мониторить, что происходит при нажатии на кнопку, после чего пробовать повторить powershell`ом.

Comment: Вот все доступные в RDS коммандлеты https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/jj215451.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396